# Detect Dialog is visible and get its instance from library code

Tags: android, dialog

I am developing android library which needs to take screenshot of dialogs of app which integrates it. I want to do this without need for client app to pass `Dialog` instance. Is there any way of getting `Dialog` instance from library code.

Now i am using this approach :

```
//to take Dialog screenshot
MyLib.takeScreenshot(Dialog dialog);
```

Is there any way i can replace the need to call this mehod?? ... detect Dialog automatically and get its instance.

Comment: I wonder 'if you had detected Dialog automatically and got it's instance' how you would continue to take a screenshot. Which method would you call then?

Comment: I have already implemented Screenshot logic. It is possible.

Comment: I do not doubt that. But it's no answer to my question ofcourse.

Comment: have u got any solution ?

Comment: have you got any solution @AdhikariBishwash?